# Can skipping `fsck` on boot impact serial-port communication?

Tags: ext4, serial-port, fsck, qt

I have a bizarre serial-port (RS-232) communications issue (it appears that some data is being dropped, though I'm not sure if it's outgoing, incoming, or both) that I'm observing sporadically. I've been having trouble reproducing it, and I was just told that the few times we *have* seen the issue arise, the Linux machine running my app was first shut down using `shutdown -fh now`, which skips `fsck` on reboot.

Even so, the communications problem usually doesn't occur until the app performing the serial communication on the Linux machine has been running for a while--somewhere between half an hour and several hours.

Is it possible for there to be some sort of latent file-system issue that could cause instability in the serial-port communication layer?

It also appears that shortly before I see the error, the [serial-port class I'm using](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) emits a "ResourceError". The Qt document describes a resource-error as:

> An I/O error occurred when a resource becomes unavailable, e.g. when the device is unexpectedly removed from the system.

Does that sound like something that could occur as the result of skipping a `fsck`...?

I'm using `ext4` for my filesystem format.

Comment: Not enough information to troubleshoot the actual issue but I can't see how the two would be related, especially considering that they're not happening at the same time and only occur when you don't do an `fsck`.  The only possibility would be a partition error that gets fixed when you do run it and that is certainly what you should look for first though.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Sorry, I know there's not really enough information to actually *fix* my issue here, so that's not what I'm expecting--I'm just hoping for something like "yes, file-system issues due to skipping `fsck` *can* affect how serial-ports work because <reason>" or "no, these are completely unrelated because `fsck` doesn't affect how device-files in `/dev/` behave" (or whatever). When you say "when you do run it" do you mean when `fsck` is eventually run?

Comment: The serial port communication itself could not be impacted by a disk error but a program that reads the disk and does serial port communications could be impacted by errors on the drive.  That is why I told you to check the result of your `fsck`s which would certainly indicate it, should it fix any error.

Comment: @JuliePelletier It doesn't look like my main partition has any errors. I can't check my swap partition because I apparently don't have `fsck.swap`, but at this point I think it's a stretch to think that a file-system error is related to my serial-port error. Thanks for your help!